# When in Python interactive shell, can I copy the previous command to the clipboard?

Tags: python, python-interactive

Is there a command in the interactive shell that copies the last expression to the clipboard?

I know there's the `_` command, which repeats the last expression's evaluation, e.g.

```
>>>  " ".join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
'a b c'
>>> _
'a b c'
```

But what I'm looking for is a command that copies `" ".join(['a', 'b', 'c'])` to the clipboard. Is there such a thing?

Comment: Which interactive shell are you using? IDLE?

Comment: If you're in Windows console, you want to open the properties of the console window, enable the QuickEdit mode and then you'll be able to select using left mouse button and copy using right mouse button. Right mouse button is for pasting as well, if nothing is selected.

Comment: There are modules you can install, like `pyperclip`, that contain functions for copying into and out of the clipboard.

Comment: @khelwood - thanks for the pointer. I'll maybe try and roll my own, together with `pyreadline` one day.

Comment: Why the downvote? (I'm genuinely interested to know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with your terminal emulator's tools.

In Python itself, there's no such functionality -- but one can add a user-supplied magic command for IPython -- [here's one for Linux and MacOS](https://gist.github.com/nova77/5403446).

Comment: I'll accept this answer as it comes closest to what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use ipython terminal..

```
$ ipython

Python 3.6.6 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jun 28 2018, 11:07:29) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.



In [1]: " ".join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
Out[1]: 'a b c'

In [2]: _
Out[2]: 'a b c'

In [3]: _1
Out[3]: 'a b c'

In [4]: __
Out[4]: 'a b c'

In [5]: _
Out[5]: 'a b c'

In [6]: _1
Out[6]: 'a b c'
```